# Como indentar em formato JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Sou leigo ainda na linguagem, queria que o JSON ficasse indentado.

Tenho o texto em uma linha:

```
[{"titulo":"teste","detalhes":"teste"}]
```

Queria ficasse da seguinte forma:

```
[
    {
        "titulo": "teste",
        "detalhes": "teste1"
    }
]
```

Esse é o código:

```
var json = [];
    json.push({
        titulo: document.getElementById('iptTitulo').value,
        detalhes: document.getElementById('iptDetalhes').value
    });

document.getElementById('text-area').value = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Comment: E onde está esse JSON? O que está fazendo com ele? Como está exibindo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss postei código

Comment: Seria algo como `JSON.stringify(json, null, '\t')` o que precisa?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esse mesmo, valeu. Deu certo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para exibir indentado seu JSON, basta utilizar o terceiro parâmetro do [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), que recebe uma *string* que será utilizada para os recuos.

```js
const json = {"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false};

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, '····'));
```

Se passar o terceiro parâmetro como um número inteiro, ele representará a quantidade de espaços em brancos utilizados no recuo.

```js
const json = {"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false};

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
```